# Create connected and disconnected callback for a binding socket using C#?

Tags: sockets, binding

I have this binding socket:

```
 Socket mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
 mainSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 0));
```

And I need to know when an extern client is connected and disconnected from my servicies( ftp, database server, app server, etc).
thank for advance.

What I have tried:
I tried with these methods but, did not work for me.

```
mainSocket.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 0), new AsyncCallback(ClientConnected), null);
mainSocket.BeginDisconnect(true, new AsyncCallback(ClientDisconnected), null);

   private void ClientDisconnected(IAsyncResult ar)
   {
       // here get some client info like Ip
   }

   private void ClientConnected(IAsyncResult ar)
   {
       // here get some client info like Ip
   }
```

I need some help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[`BeginConnect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.beginconnect?view=net-5.0) and [`BeginDisconnect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.begindisconnect?view=net-5.0) are asynchronous operations.  They are not events you can subscribe to.

`BeginConnect()` is for a client socket to asynchronously open a new connection to a server.  `BeginDisconnect()` asynchronously closes an open socket.

To detect clients connecting to your server, you need to use [`Accept()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.accept?view=net-5.0), [`BeginAccept()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.beginaccept?view=net-5.0)/[`EndAccept()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.endaccept?view=net-5.0), or [`AcceptAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.acceptasync?view=net-5.0) to accept inbound connections coming into your server socket.  You will be given a new `Socket` for each accepted client to use for communicating with them.

There is no event for a client disconnecting from a server.  If a client disconnects, pending/subsequent send/receive operations involving that client will fail.  You need to handle those failures when they occur.  For instance, if a client disconnects *gracefully*, a read operation from the client will end as *successful* with 0 bytes reported.  But if the client disconnects abnormally, a read operation will end as *failed* with an error code reported.